# need help in implementation of trie in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

```
class node {

     public:
     node(){
       value  = 0;
       arr = new node*[26];
       for(int i =0 ; i<26;i++)
         arr[i]= NULL;
       }
      int  value;
      node ** arr ;
};
class trie {
     public:
        trie(){
           root = NULL;
        }
     node * root;
     int count;
};
int main(){
        string A[5] = {"apple, ball , bat , cat, car"};
        trie* too;
        node *p = new node();
        too->root = p; // **here**
}
```

**Here** :i am having a runtime error.. to me its seems to be correct ..I have no idea whats wrong with it. Any help would be of Great Use to me :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`too` isn't pointing to anything.

The simplest fix is to remove the * to make it a local object instead of a pointer.

```
int main(){
    string A[5] = {"apple, ball , bat , cat, car"};
    trie too; //<------ Fix here
    node *p = new node();
    too->root = p; // **here**
}
```

Alternatively, you can `new` a `trie` object. But for your purposes that is unnecessary.